# HttpWebRequest in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

im making an app in wpf, which uses a restful api, from sharefile im making the autorisation 
so far i have this

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://secure.sharefile.com/oauth/authorize");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
        shareFileWebView.Navigate(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        shareFileWebView.  // but i supose to get something from here 
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        JObject token = null;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            token = JObject.Parse(body);
        }

        OAuth2Token _tokene =new OAuth2Token(token);

    }
```

i need to get that token but how can i get from the webbrowser? in the webr browser the user fills his accounts data, any ideas??

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  How do you get the link for the file you uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Does this link give you what you need?
  http://api.sharefile.com/rest/api-key.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Http request with body ( for example send image ) :

```
public string httpRequest(string url,byte[] image)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "Post";
                request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
                request.ContentLength = image.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                    postStream.Close();
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
                        return responseString;
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

or :

```
  public string RunCommand()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();

            return responseString;
        }
```